# Transform Probability

Tags: probability

If I have one probability function which is successful 1/4 and unsuccessful 3/4 of the time.  Is there a way to transform this probability to one that is equal 1/2, 1/2.  You can have as many samples for the first probability function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it could be phrased like this: We have events $E_i$ that independently occur with probability $\frac14$; does the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these events contain an event with probability $\frac12$?

If we have a finite number of these events, the answer is no. For $n$ generating events, the probabilities of all elements are fractions with denominator $4^n=2^{2n}$. Thus the probability $\frac12$ would correspond to a numerator $2^{2n-1}$. The remainder of $2^{2n-1}$ modulo $3$ is $2$. But the numerators of the probabilities of the elementary events $\bigcap_i A_i$, where each $A_i$ is either $E_i$ or $\overline{E_i}$, are all divisible by $3$ except for the case where all $A_i$ are $E_i$, where the numerator is $1$. Thus no conjunction of these elementary events can have a probability whose remainder modulo $3$ is $2$.